# Dropdown, side bar or second nav bar for a submenu in a website?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, navigation

What is the best form/ position for a submenu in a website, a dropdown for the menu item, a list in a sidebar or a second nav bar?

Comment: As with many UI / UX questions, there isn't necessarily a 'one size fits all' answer and this sort of question especially requires more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- Don't make users scroll, and make it as *visible* as possible.

  - Second navigation bar for a small number of items.
  - Side bar for a medium number of items.
  - Mega-menus for a sub-menu with a number of categories.
- Mobile navigation is too broad of a subject to address.

---

## Second navigation bar for a small number of items

The [Nielsen Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/accordions-complex-content/) [regularly](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/menu-design/) notes that:

> Hiding content behind navigation diminishes people’s awareness of it.

This is mirrored by [Don Norman in the Design of Everyday Things](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1452654123), who says:

> In each state of the system, the user **must readily see and be able to do the allowable actions**. The visibility acts as a suggestion reminding the user of the possibilities.

So if possible, **don't hide your navigation**.

Use a form of navigation which **makes the user's options immediately visible**, such as a second navigation bar.

An added advantage is that the user will also have fewer *types* of navigation to contend with.

---

## Side-bar for a medium number of items

If you can't fit your items on a second navigation bar, the next best thing is a side-bar.

**But only if your users won't need to scroll** to see the items at the bottom.

If they do, a mega-menu might be more suitable.

---

## Mega-menus for a large number of items

It's sometimes not possible to show all items.

[Nielsen and Li (March 2017)](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-work-well/) describe in detail why mega-menus work so well for categorised navigation with a large number of items.

They summarise by saying:

> Large, rectangular menus group navigation options to **eliminate scrolling** and use typography, icons, and tooltips to **explain users' choices**.

They also note the **advantages over a standard drop-down menu**:

> - For bigger sites with many features, regular dropdown menus **typically hide most of the user's options**. Yes, you can scroll, but (a) it's a pain, and (b) scrolling hides the options at the top of the menu. As a result, **you can't visually compare all your choices; you have to rely on short-term memory**.
> - Mega menus let you **visually emphasize relationships among items**. This again helps users understand their choices.
> - Mega menus make it **easy to use pictures and icons when appropriate**. And, even if you stick to text alone, you have richer typography at your disposal (letting you differentiate link sizes according to their importance, for example).

---

### How about mobile?

I've intentionally not addressed mobile because it's a **very broad area to cover**.

For those wanting to delve into it, here's some great places to start:

- [**Nielsen Group**: Basic Patterns for Mobile Navigation: A Primer](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-navigation-patterns/)
- [**UX Planet**: Basic Patterns for Mobile Navigation](https://uxplanet.org/basic-patterns-for-mobile-navigation-d12a87686efe)
- [**UXPin**: 5 Creative Mobile UI Patterns for Navigation](https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/5-creative-mobile-ui-patterns-navigation/)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I don't see any reference about sidebars. What do you think about this option? I fact, I need to redesign a website that has submenus as dropdowns, but also in the sidebar. For me, the choice was, at the beginning, the second nav, but I wanted to see more opinions.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina If you can implement the sidebar without needing the user to scroll to see the bottom items, I would favour it to a mega-menu as it'll improve visibility. But if you can fit it on a second navigation bar, do so. Then the user will have fewer *types* of navigation to contend with.

Comment: Can you update the answer and insert a reference to sidebars, like in your comment, please? The comment was more clarifying for me, more accurate. Thanks.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina Thanks for the feedback, I've added a section regarding side-bars to my answer.